# Making WebViews work with Master Details

Tags: java, android, android-webview, master-detail

This is for Android Studio v2.3. All I want to do is to have a master detail flow where I click into one of the items on the list and that brings me to the website. After looking at all the different recommendations, my app still just force quits or "doesn't respond" whenever I click any items on the list. Please help!

WebPageDetailFragment.java code:

```
package com.example.jasperzhu.moremorelearning;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.example.jasperzhu.moremorelearning.dummy.DummyContent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

/**
 * A fragment representing a single Webpage detail screen.
 * This fragment is either contained in a {@link WebpageListActivity}
 * in two-pane mode (on tablets) or a {@link WebpageDetailActivity}
 * on handsets.
 */
public class WebpageDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the item ID that this fragment
     * represents.
     */
    public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

    /**
     * The dummy content this fragment is presenting.
     */
    private DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public WebpageDetailFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
            // Load the dummy content specified by the fragment
            // arguments. In a real-world scenario, use a Loader
            // to load content from a content provider.
            mItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));

            Activity activity = this.getActivity();
            CollapsingToolbarLayout appBarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
            if (appBarLayout != null) {
                appBarLayout.setTitle(mItem.content);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webpage_detail, container, false);

        if (mItem != null) {
            WebView view = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webpage);
            view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //for some web using JavaScript like "youtube.com"
            view.loadUrl(mItem.address);
            view.setLayerType(view.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }

        return rootView;
     }
  }
```

DummyContent.java code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Helper class for providing sample content for user interfaces created by
 * Android template wizards.
 * <p>
 * TODO: Replace all uses of this class before publishing your app.
 */
public class DummyContent {

    public static final List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<DummyItem>();

    public static final Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, DummyItem>();

    static {
        addItem(new DummyItem("Google", "Google", "www.google.com"));
        addItem(new DummyItem("Bing", "Bing", "www.bing.com"));
        addItem(new DummyItem("Baidu", "Baidu", "www.baidu.com"));
    }

    private static void addItem(DummyItem item) {
        ITEMS.add(item);
        ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
    }

    private static String makeDetails(int position) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Details about Item: ").append(position);
        for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
            builder.append("\nMore details information here.");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static class DummyItem {
        public final String id;
        public final String content;
        public String address;

        public DummyItem(String id, String content, String address) {
            this.id = id;
            this.content = content;
            this.address = address;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return content;
        }
     }
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Do you have this permissions in your androidManifest.xml?     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
What kind of error do you get?

Comment: @Steven I have that permission added. The error is simply "Unfortunately the app has stopped." If I test it on a real device, it just quits and goes to the home screen.

Comment: If you connect the device you can see what kind of error you get in the debug mode of android studio.